# jQuery: height of a div based on a different div

Tags: jquery, height

I'm trying to make the height of an element based on the height of a parent element in jQuery with little success. My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav li:hover ul li ul').height() = $('#nav li ul').height() - 5;
    $('#nav li ul li ul').height() = $('#nav li ul').height() - 5;
});
```

Any ideas why this won't work?

Answer (score 1):

`.height` is a function, so when you call `.height()`, you can't assign a value to it. In jQuery you can set an element's height by passing in the new height as an argument to the `.height` function.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#nav li:hover ul li ul').height($('#nav li ul').height() - 5);
        $('#nav li ul li ul').height($('#nav li ul').height() - 5);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using it wrong...

```
$('#element').height( $('#otherelement').height() );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the height of an element then pass the height as first argument to `height` method of jQuery object as shown below. When you don't pass any argument to `height` method it returns the height of the first element in the matched set of elements.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav li:hover ul li ul').height($('#nav li ul').height() - 5);
    $('#nav li ul li ul').height($('#nav li ul').height() - 5);
});
```